# How to use local files to short cut git clone

Tags: git, clone, atlassian-sourcetree, git-clone, local-files

I have a big project (~10 GB) and want my teammates to clone it. We all work in the same office. Since we are located at the same place I want to give them the files by flash disk and complete their cloning with downloading everything over internet.

How can this be done?

I'm expecting something like people do with their steam account. Start downloading a game, quit steam app, copy local backup files to the download folder, restart steam, continue download and steam checks the files and completes the download process.

Comment: Just copy your repository folder from your local machine to a usb drive and make them copy it? I don't think there's any magic here. If the remote url setup is personalized (ie. contains your username or password or whatnot), then they might need to remove and re-add the upstream url.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've copied the files, sourcetree > add repository > change credentials.

There is also another situation, I'll ask in a new question.